# Multiple shipping companies for a single store in Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

can we have different shipping companies like UPS for online store and some other company for wholesale store for a same company(store)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. That is pretty easy. You decide how to fulfill your orders. When an order is placed, you can choose your fulfillment service.

Comment: sorry i did some mistake while typing i edited it can you re-read it and ans it if you can

Comment: My answer remains the same. You can have as many types of fulfillment for your shop as you need. It is all programmable.